# replacing numbers in a string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, integer

I have string that contains numbers and characters. I want to replace the numbers with another value that will give it a css class of `someClass`.

Now I got the code to detect all the numbers in the string and replace it with something else.

My question is how do I get the current number match and put it to the new string or value that will replace the original one?

Basically what I want to happen is:

for example, I have this string: `1dog3cat`, I want it to get replaced with `<span class="someClass">1</span>dog<span class="someClass">3</span>cat`

Here's my current code:

```
    var string_variable;
    string_variable = "1FOO5,200BAR";
    string_variable = string_variable.replace(/(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g, "<span class='someClass'>" + string_variable + "</span>");
    alert(string_variable);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remember the matched pattern using parenthesis and retrieve that value using `$1` and add `span` tag to it.

Use this regex

```
string_variable = string_variable.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<span class='someClass'>$1</span>");
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY0fR6/6)

Comment: used this answer. thanks @Ankit, going to accept this answer. :)